# How do I map my ViewModel's ID to the Document ID in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have the fetch Data code here, but I don't understand how I am supposed to delete documents without setting the ID to the Document's ID. I was following this tutorial here. https://medium.com/swift-productions/swiftui-easy-to-do-list-with-firebase-2637c878cf1a I'm assuming I need to do so in the data mapping but I don't understand how with this code. I want to remove a todo from a SwiftUI list and also delete it's entire Firestore Document.

```
func fetchData() {
    db.collection("todos").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.todos = documents.map { (QueryDocumentSnapshot)  -> Todo in
            let data = QueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            let todoDetails = data["todo"] as? String ?? ""
            
            return Todo(todoDetais: todoDetails)
        }
    }
}
```

View Model

```
struct Todo: Codable, Identifiable {
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
var todoDetais: String?
```

}

Comment: Why you don't want to use the document ID? You would need some kind of identifier. Best you could do is add the UID you want in the Firestore document. Then when deleting first you would have to fetch that document ID and then delete which makes it a two step process then. I'd suggest adding the document ID in the Model like `return Todo(todoDetais: todoDetails, firestoreID: docID)` so I can access it whenever I need.

Comment: I'm still not sure how this maps the view model's ID to the Firestore's Document ID. @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Codable to map your Firestore documents to Swift structs. This will make your code easier to write, less prone to errors, and more type-safe.

Specifically, it will also enable you to use `@DocumentID` to map the Firestore document ID to the `id` attribute of your Swift struct.

Here's a quick example:

```swift
struct Book: Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String? 
  var title: String
  var numberOfPages: Int
  var author: String
}

func fetchBook(documentId: String) {
  let docRef = db.collection("books").document(documentId)
  docRef.getDocument { document, error in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
      self.errorMessage = "Error getting document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
    }
    else {
      if let document = document {
        do {
          self.book = try document.data(as: Book.self) 
        }
        catch {
          print(error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more details, see [this comprehensive guide](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/) I wrote about mapping Firestore documents to Swift structs (and back).

For more information about how to delete a Firestore document from a SwiftUI app, check out [this article](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-update-data/#deleting-a-book)